# Gradle won't sync when trying to add build-logic

Tags: android, gradle

So I'm stuck with the following issue.

The general idea is to try implement what exists in [nia app](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid) regarding build-logic with convention plugins.

Following code syncs correctly:

**Project settings**

```
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("build-logic")
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "gradleversioncatalogssample"
enableFeaturePreview("TYPESAFE_PROJECT_ACCESSORS")
include(":app")
include(":feature:feature1")
```

**/build-logic/settings.gradle.kts**

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from(files("../gradle/libs.versions.toml"))
        }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "build-logic"
include(":convention")
```

**/build-logic/convention/build.gradle.kts**

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

group = "com.test.gradleversioncatalogssample.buildlogic"

// Configure the build-logic plugins to target JDK 19
// This matches the JDK used to build the project, and is not related to what is running on device.
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_19
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_19
}
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_19.toString()
    }
}

tasks {
    validatePlugins {
        enableStricterValidation = true
        failOnWarning = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly(libs.android.gradlePlugin)
    compileOnly(libs.android.tools.common)
    compileOnly(libs.kotlin.gradlePlugin)
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        register("androidLibrary") {
            id = "gradleversioncatalogssample.android.library"
            implementationClass = "AndroidLibraryConventionPlugin"
        }
    }
}
```

**/app/build.gradle.kts**
`default one`

**/feature/feature1/build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinAndroid)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.test.feature1"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_19
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_19
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "19"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
}
```

**libs.versions.toml**

```
...
[plugins]
...
gradleversioncatalogssample-android-library = { id="gradleversioncatalogssample.android.library", version = "unspecified" }
...
```

**AndroidLibraryConventionPlugin**

```
class AndroidLibraryConventionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {

        with(target) {
            with(pluginManager) {
                apply("com.android.library")
                apply("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")

            }

            extensions.configure<LibraryExtension> {
                compileSdk = 34
                defaultConfig {
                    minSdk = 21
                    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                }
                compileOptions {
                    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_19
                    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_19
                }
                tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
                    kotlinOptions {
                        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_19.toString()

                    }
                }
                defaultConfig.targetSdk = 34

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code syncs successfully.
When i change the **/feature/feature1/build.gradle.kts** to the following:

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.gradleversioncatalogssample.android.library)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.test.feature1"
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
}
```

I get a sync error.

```
Unresolved reference: core
Unresolved reference: appcompat
Unresolved reference: material
Unresolved reference: junit
Unresolved reference: androidx
Unresolved reference: espresso
```

Please note that the **libs part** is successfully found.

```
ScriptCompilationException(scriptCompilationErrors=[ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: core, location=/Users/<user>/.gradle/.tmp/gradle-kotlin-dsl-3878259200151468629.tmp/build.gradle.kts (11:25)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: appcompat, location=/Users/<user>/.gradle/.tmp/gradle-kotlin-dsl-3878259200151468629.tmp/build.gradle.kts (12:25)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: material, location=/Users/<user>/.gradle/.tmp/gradle-kotlin-dsl-3878259200151468629.tmp/build.gradle.kts (13:25)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: junit, location=/Users/<user>/.gradle/.tmp/gradle-kotlin-dsl-3878259200151468629.tmp/build.gradle.kts (14:29)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: androidx, location=/Users/<user>/.gradle/.tmp/gradle-kotlin-dsl-3878259200151468629.tmp/build.gradle.kts (15:36)), ScriptCompilationError(message=Unresolved reference: espresso, location=/Users/<user>/.gradle/.tmp/gradle-kotlin-dsl-3878259200151468629.tmp/build.gradle.kts (16:36))])
    at org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.support.KotlinCompilerKt.compileKotlinScriptModuleTo(KotlinCompiler.kt:205)
<More code here>
```

What am i missing?

I tried different setup, starting project from scratch, invalidating cache